# Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, sdk

I stumbled upon this issue during the implementation of a SDK when I had to create a ViewController. The answers I saw before were not very detailed or didn't solve my issue. What I have answered below worked for me, and I hope it helps somebody else. I am using Xcode 14.1.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your project in Xcode under **Targets** sections that is on the left menu
2. Go to **Build Phases** and scroll down to the section called *Compile Sources*
3. You should see a **+** and **-** icon and bottom left of this section, click on the + icon
4. A pop up should be opened with a list of files in Compile Sources, this windows should also have a button called **Add Other...**
5. Click Add Other and select the files you want to add to Compile Sources
6. After the selection a window pop ups with the name **Choose options for adding these files:**, from three options choose **Create Folder references** and click the **Finish** button
7. Try to make another build and the error should be gone